# sorting text columns in Python

Tags: python, text-files

I am a very novice coder who needs help combining and rearranging a lot of .txt data. The file is currently listed as follows:

```
A

lcorn, MS
Aleutians East, AK
Aleutians West, AK
Alexander, IL
Alexander, NC
Alexandria, VA
Alfalfa, OK
Alger, MI
Allamakee, IA
Allegan, MI
Allegany, MD
Allegany, NY
Alleghany, NC
Alleghany, VA
Allegheny, PA
Allen, IN
Allen, KS
Allen, KY
Allen, LA
Allen, OH
Allendale, SC
Alpena, MI
Alpine, CA
Amador, CA
Amelia, VA
Amherst, VA
Amite, MS
```

I need to rearrange the data so it reads like

```
MS: Alcorn
AK: Aleutians East
AK: Aleutians West
```

Essentially in the format of `(State): County`. I then need to output the newly completed results into a new text file, there are hundreds of lines in the file and I am unaware of where to even start.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to iterate over your data reading it one line at a time, then reformat the `county, state` as `state: county`.

Try:

```python
with open('data.txt', "r") as fin, open('out.dat', "w") as fout:
    line = fin.readline()    
    while line:
        pos = line.rfind(',')
        if pos > 1:
            # input: Aleutians West, AK
            # reformat AK: Aleutians West
            line = "{}: {}".format(line[pos+1:].strip(), line[0:pos])
            fout.write(line)
        elif line.strip() != '':
            # otherwise no comma so not in county, state form
            print("skip:", line)
        line = fin.readline()
```

Output:

```
MS: Alcorn
AK: Aleutians East
AK: Aleutians West
IL: Alexander
NC: Alexander
...
```

A comma (,) might be found in a county name, so code above is using `line.rfind(',')` to find the last ',' in the line. If no lines have more than one comma in them then you can safely use `line.find(',')` to find the first comma.

Next, if you want to sort the output file by state and county then you can do it in Python code or use the "sort" command found on most operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is as simple as it looks, a simple answer could be:

```
with open('outfile.txt','wt') as ofile:
    for line in open('infile.txt','rt'):
        city,state = list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),line.split(","))
        print(f"{state} : {city}",file=ofile)
```

or something quite similar (not tested.)

Answer (score 0):

string="""lcorn, MS
Aleutians East, AK
Aleutians West, AK
Alexander, IL
Alexander, NC
Alexandria, VA
Alfalfa, OK
Alger, MI
Allamakee, IA
Allegan, MI
Allegany, MD
Allegany, NY
Alleghany, NC
Alleghany, VA
Allegheny, PA
Allen, IN
Allen, KS
Allen, KY
Allen, LA
Allen, OH
Allendale, SC
Alpena, MI
Alpine, CA
Amador, CA
Amelia, VA
Amherst, VA
Amite, MS"""

```
 myTuples=[tuple(item.split(',')) for item in string.split("\n")]
 myDict={}
 for (key,value) in myTuples:
     myDict[key]=value

 result={k: v for k, v in sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
 print(result)
```